# After decimal only show 4 digit while selecting whole table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, rounding

I have a report in which values like `222.4444444444444` is displayed. Now I want to display it like `222.4444`

The issue is that I want it for all the table columns and there are 33 columns.

`SELECT  * FROM IPFEE_MST_INSRT_ASCEND`

Comment: It would be better to address a display task to the UI layer. What is the actual issue: number of columns? how to format the value in this particular way? how to round the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` and list all the columns:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(col1, 'fm99990D0000') AS col1,
       TO_CHAR(col2, 'fm99990D0000') AS col2,
       TO_CHAR(col3, 'fm99990D0000') AS col3,
       TO_CHAR(col4, 'fm99990D0000') AS col4
FROM   table_name
```